# Ignore unknown attributes when assigning attributes to an object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a way to ignore attributes that are set to be assigned to an object if that object does not have that/those attributes?

For example:

```
Object has id, field1
```

Person issues `Object.create(field1: 'test', cheese: 'test1')`

Is there a way to go ahead and create the object and ignore that the person tried to assign a value to cheese?

Comment: A `seeds.rb` can help new people on a project get started quickly. Why wouldn't you want to clean up your `seeds.rb` if it is no longer up to date?

Comment: On a similar note, I've found reusing factories from your specs is great for generating seed data. Keeps data generation in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a way to ignore them without just as much work as cleaning up the file.  However, you can use this:

https://github.com/rroblak/seed_dump

To dump your current dev db to a seed file, sometimes it's easier to use destroy to dump records you don't need from the console and create the seed file using the gem than manually.